# Loop thru nested DIV element

Tags: jquery

What would be the best approach to traverse nested div element to get the label text?

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="div0">
    <span class="ui-icon"></span>
    <label>some data</label>
  </div>
  <div id="div1">
    <span class="ui-icon"></span>
    <label>some data1</label>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <span class="ui-icon"></span>
    <label>some data2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Trying something like following but getting undefined,

```
$('#parent > div > span > label').each(function () {
                    console.log($(this).value); // "this" is the current element in the loop
 });
```

Comment: Labels don't have a value. Also `value` is vanilla javasctipt `.val()` is jquery. Try `.html()` or [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues:

1) Your selector is looking for a `label` that is a child of `span` when it is a sibling. Use a [sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) [combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) instead

2) Labels do not have a `value`, they have [`innerHtml`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) etc. For jquery you want to use [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/);

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parent > div > span + label').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text()); // "this" is the current element in the loop
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="div0">
    <span class="ui-icon"></span>
    <label>some data</label>
  </div>
  <div id="div1">
    <span class="ui-icon"></span>
    <label>some data1</label>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <span class="ui-icon"></span>
    <label>some data2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```